Connected partitions of bounded-degree bounded-rank hypergraphs
Some definitions: A hypergraph has vertices and hyperedges, where each hyperedge is a nonempty subset of the vertex-set (I am allowing singletons) and no two hyperedges are equal. The degree of a vertex is the number of hyperedges it is contained in, and the order of a hyperedge is the number of vertices it contains. Two distinct vertices are adjacent if they are both contained in some hyperedge. A path is a sequence of distinct vertices such that any two consecutive vertices are adjacent. A hypergraph is connected if there is a path between any two vertices.
Given a subset of vertices, the induced subgraph on that subset is the set of all hyperedges contained in that subset. A connected partition of a hypergraph is a partition of the vertices such that the induced subgraph on every part is connected. Two distinct parts in a partition are said to be adjacent if there is a hyperedge containing a vertex from both parts.

Let $\mathcal G_\Delta$ be the collection of finite connected hypergraphs where the degree of every vertex and the order of every hyperedge is at most $\Delta \ge 1$. (The incidence graph of a hypergraph is a bipartite graph. Conversely, every bipartite graph is the incidence graph of a hypergraph. So, equivalently, one can think of $\mathcal G_\Delta$ as the collection of finite connected bipartite graphs with maximum degree $\Delta$.)
Question: Are there real constants $c\ge 1$ and $r\ge 1$ such that for every positive integer $k$, every hypergraph in $\mathcal G_\Delta$ with at least $k$ vertices has a connected partition such that

every part has at most $c k^r$ vertices, and
no two parts with fewer than $k$ vertices are adjacent?


I have asked a related question on mathoverflow here, but it is a stronger version of the above question. In short, when the hypergraph is graph with maximum degree $\Delta$, I show that the answer is yes by ensuring that every part has at least $k$ vertices and at most $c k^r$ vertices (I first proved this for trees, and that proof can be extended to graphs by taking a spanning tree). So we never have to deal with condition 2 in case of graphs. For hypergraphs, I give an example where there are always parts with fewer than $k$ vertices, so we are forced to take care of the second condition. But, in that example, it is easy to show that both conditions 1 and 2 can be ensured. So I believe that that answer to the above (weaker) question is yes. Any help in proving it is much appreciated.
